# Defining a textview in another class than the "main" class

Tags: android, eclipse, textview

I have a main application with a button defined in layout.xml.

When I click on the button, I want to call a method located in another class, and when I try to create a TextView in that class, I must provide an argument to the new TextView(???) command, and I don't know what to do.

I reckon that this is a 2 seconds question for you folks, and for me, newbiiie as it is, it is a tough one.

Just in case, here are the relevant sections of code:

The section of the main class that is applicable:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public DateAndTime cur_datetime = new DateAndTime();
    public LongLat cur_longlat = new LongLat();
    public int current_location_number = 0;
    public ArrayList<LocationInfo> locations = null;
     Button doSunButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addListenersForButtons();
            dosomething();
    }

public void addListenersForButtons()
{
    doSunButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dosun_button_id);
    doSunButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener()
 {

@Override
  public void onClick(View arg0) 
  {
DoSun myDoSun = new DoSun();
Log.v("button", "Am I really calling from the button function...");
myDoSun.doSun2(locations, current_location_number);
} // end of dosun on click on dosun_id button
                        ); // end of define listener

  } // end of addListenersForButtons(0) method
}
```

The class whose method is called:

```
package com.example.sunandmoon;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DoSun extends Activity{

    public void doSun2(ArrayList<LocationInfo> locations, int current_location_number)
    {
        //Log.v("doSun", "Am I really there!");
        TextView textViewsunrise = new TextView(??????);
        textViewsunrise = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sunrise_id);
        ((TextView)textViewsunrise).setText("From DoSun2! " + locations.get(current_location_number).getnameGiven());
    } // end of doSun(0) method

}
```

And by the way, I also wonder how I could avoid passing the two parameters  current_location_numberv and ArrayList locations to the doSun2 method, since they "should be" globals (you can see that I come from C...).

Thank you for your help.

And to you flamers of all kinds, yes, I have tried to find an answer to this...

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: why does DoSun extends Activity ? why do you call new TextView _and_ findViewById ?

Comment: See my answer  Actually, the root of the solution depends on whether `DoSun` should be an `Activity` or not.  Is it a separate screen, which will display the `TextView` you create?

Comment: @Simon thank you very much! All 5 points are good learning for me. I shall chew on it and fix the code accordingly. Maybe you can look at my newest question, also something most likely easy for somebody like you, and thank you again for your patience...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code.

1. Do not use classes extended from `Activity` for anything other than, er, being Activities!  An `Activity` represents a single task focused object with which the user interacts.  Loosely, think of each screen in an app as being an `Activity`.
2. "should be globals".  No they should not.  There are occasional situations in Android in which globals make sense.  This is not one of them.  You should not avoid passing the arguments to `doSun2()` since it behaves according to those arguments.  It would be completely anti-pattern to use globals.
3. The `TextView` you want to create rightly belongs to `MainActivity`.  It should be responsible for creating and managing it.  To do this, have the method in DoSun take arguments (locations, currentLocationNumber) and have it return a structure of some sort with all of the values you need to create the `TextView` back in `MainActivity`.  You could create a helper method in `MainActivity` which takes the structure returned by `doSun2()` as an argument and returns a new `TextView` ready for adding to the `Activity` `Layout`.
4. In general, only Activities should create and manage any UI elements.
5. If `DoSun` really should be an Activity, then do not attempt to create an instance of it via it's constructors.  Instead, create an `Intent` and use `startActivity` to create it.

All this said, you should get into the habit of describing **what** you want to achieve, since your approach (which I have responded to) may not be the right one.

Good luck!